# Derivatives Applications Problem

Tags: derivatives

My teacher dropped this problem in class but no one seemed to answer it correctly. Any help?
A man is walking from his front door to his car. The length of garden from his door to the road is 4 m. The car is parked 10 m up the road. Because of snow, he can only walk at 0.4 m/s through the garden, and 0.5 m/s on the road. What route should he take to minimize the time taken to get to his car?

Set it up like this: Let x be the from the end of the path to the point on the road that he aims for.

Then find expressions for each of the two parts of his journey, and use the corresponding speeds to determine the time taken for each part.

Find an expression for the total time and minimize it.
[image]

Comment: Unless you engage and show some work, you are likely to get down votes or close votes. So please do so and quickly. I've started the problem for you below.

Comment: In addition I took into account the time for diagonal walk through the garden.

Comment: This is actually a pretty important problem. A very similar (identical?) setup shows why light refracts when changing media. See [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph5B/fermat09.pdf) for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far have you got already?

Write the total time $T = t_{road} + t_{snow} = f(x)$. The time taken for the road segment is

$$t_{road} = \frac{Distance}{Speed} = \frac{10-x}{0.5} = 20 - 2x$$

What's the expression for $t_{snow}$? And hence what is $T = f(x)$?

---

*Added:* From below, the total time is $$T = f(x) = \frac{5}{2} \sqrt{x^2 + 16} - 2x + 20$$ Differentiating,

$$f'(x) = \frac{5}{2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 16}} - 2$$

which is equal to zero if $$5x = 4\sqrt{x^2 + 16}$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: But the point is, I don't really know how to do it. That's why I posted it here :(. I can try though... Ts = distance/speed=4-x/0.4?

Comment: Oh Wait! it is Ts = Sqrt(4^2+x^2)/0.4

Comment: Yes, by Pythagorus's Theorem, we have that distance through the snow. Hence

$$t_{snow} = \frac{\sqrt{16 + x^2}}{0.4} = \frac{5}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + 16}$$

Thus the total time is

$$T = f(x) = \frac{5}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + 16}  - 2x + 20$$

Now find its minimum on the interval $x \in [0,10]$.

Comment: When you say min ∈[0,10] you mean 0<x<10? if so, I think the answer is x = 16/3 ( that is the minimum)

Comment: $x \in [0,10]$ means $0 \leq x \leq 10$. I included the end points as in theory, the minimum could have been at one of them. But it turns out it is at an point inside the interval, where the derivative is zero:  the minimum is attained at $x = 16/3$ meters.

Comment: So the answer is ((sqrt(4^2+(16/3)^2))/0.4) + (20-2(16/3)) = 26 seconds?

Comment: Yes. (Double checking the end points: $f(0) = 30$ and $f(10) = 5\sqrt{29} \approx 26.9$. So we're fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Minimize by differentiation:

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt { 16+x^2}}{0.4} + \dfrac {(10-x)}{0.5} $$

EDIT1:
Let $$ \sin r = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt { 16+x^2}} = \dfrac{v_1}{v_2} < 1 $$ where the last is the ratio of speeds.

It will be instructive at this stage ( taking help from your teacher) to derive Fermat's principle in Optics to find your $x$ such that

$$ \dfrac{\sin i}{  \sin r} = \mu > 1. $$

Comment: Oh you mean he should show his work? If so  I shall delete it.

Comment: You probably answered in this way to subtly tell the OP that he should show his previous work, but as stated this is way more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Indeed,  where the OP is now it is difficult to judge, when to nudge in comments or when to push or when to outright spoon-feed in answer !